# facebook login and logout from a website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, logout

I am doing a login and logout in a website with facebook account info. For that I have made my code like this

For Index.html my code is like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
     channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
     status     : true, // check login status
     cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
     xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
   });
};
// logs the user in the application and facebook
function login(){
FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
     if(r.status === 'connected'){
            window.location.href = 'fbconnect.php';
     }else{
        FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
              //if (response.perms)
                    window.location.href = 'fbconnect.php';
            } else {
              // user is not logged in
            }
     },{scope:'email'}); // which data to access from user profile
 }
});
}

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

//]]>
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='login();'>Facebook Login</a>
```

and in fbconnect.php I have my code looks like this

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    //echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>login</a>";

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    //echo $loginUrl; 
    if($user){
        $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user; 
        $_SESSION['user_pro']= $facebook->api('/me');
        echo $_SESSION['user_pro']['first_name'];
        echo $_SESSION['user_pro']['last_name'];
        echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($_SESSION);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'not logged in '; 
    }
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>log out </a>"
?>
```

As I also want logout system so that a user can also logout from the site I made the code for logout.php like this

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';  //including the facebook php sdk
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=' . YOUR_SITE_URL .
  '&access_token='.$token;
session_destroy();
header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

But here its showing error like

```
Notice: Undefined variable: facebook in logout.php on line 3 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAccessToken() on a non-object in logout.php on line 3.
```

Here it is doing login easily but in logout it is showing the error. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue? I am really newbie to facebook application. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook();  //including the facebook php sdk
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Where `$facebook` is the instance for the `Facebook` class.And as per your comments if you want to logout from facebook also then you need to destroy the session at your logout function like

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you tell me how to logout from facebook completely from the site logout. In my case it is only doing logout from the site not from facebook..

Comment: Yes I have used the same as u told but its not working. My logout.php code is like this

`<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';    //including the facebook php sdk
$facebook = new Facebook();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$url = 'index.html';
$facebook->destroySession();
session_destroy();
header('Location: '.$url);
?>`